# Different NT Groups Return Local/Server

Tags: asp.net, nt

I have two functions which list a users NT groups on an ASP.NET app

```
Private Function getUserGroups() As Boolean
        ' collect the user domain and identity
        Dim arr As String() = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split("\"c)

        Dim al As New ArrayList()
        al = GetGroups()

        For Each s As String In al
            testt.InnerHtml += s & "<br />"   
        Next

        Return auth
    End Function

    Public Function GetGroups() As ArrayList
        Dim groups As New ArrayList()
        For Each group As System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference In System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups
            groups.Add(group.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString())
        Next
        Return groups
    End Function
```

When run locally (development mode) I get a much longer list than I do when I run on the remote server:

```
Local:

DOMAIN_EX\Domain Users
Everyone
BUILTIN\Administrators
BUILTIN\Users
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
CONSOLE LOGON
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization
LOCAL
DOMAIN_EX\Eg12w
DOMAIN_EX\Eg12
DOMAIN_EX\SEC_PGP_CommunicationsGroup
DOMAIN_EX\More

Remote:

Everyone
BUILTIN\Users
CONSOLE LOGON
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization
LOCAL
```

Can anyone explain the difference and how I can solve this as I'm trying to use the array of groups to authenticate a users permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by disabling Anonymous Authentication in IIS.